# how to query direct message object from the customer community plus profile?

Tags: customer-community, connect-api

I need to retrieve direct message data from the customer community plus user profile. How to query direct message object from the customer community plus profile?
Thanks,
Prasad

Answer (score 0):

The REST endpoints to work with the Direct Message feature are written in a manner to to get the feed for one particular Direct Message. There is no rest endpoint to get all DMs in a network. So, SOQL queries run by a user with "Manage Chatter Messages and Direct Messages" user perm is the way to query for all DMs. The sample query below would be the way to do it. I will point out that this query only gives the initial Post that starts a particular Direct Message thread. When other people respond on that original DM Post, they are chatter Comments. So, that query is not going to get all the Direct Message comments. You would have to run a similar query on FeedComment.

```
SELECT 
 Title, 
 Body, 
 CommentCount, 
 CreatedById, 
 CreatedDate,
 Visibility, 
 IsDeleted, 
 NetworkScope, 
 ParentId,
 Status, 
 Type
FROM FeedItem 
WHERE 
 createdDate = THIS_WEEK
AND
 NetworkScope = 'AllNetworks'
AND
 (ParentId >= '05y000000000000' AND ParentId <= '05yzzzzzzzzzzzz')
ORDER BY
 createdDate DESC
```

So you should be able to query 'Direct Messages' of community through 'Workbench' with the 'FeedItem' object as long as the user running the query has the perm specified above

Please review [Moderate Flagged Direct Messages in Your Community](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_moderate_direct_messages.htm&type=5) and [Direct Message Limitations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_direct_messages_considerations.htm&type=5) to learn more about Direct Messages